# Finding limit supremum of a trigonometric sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

I am working out an exercise on sequences of functions. I seem to be stuck on this particular problem

Find limit supremum and limit infimum of the sequence $a_n=\cos \sqrt{t+n^2 \pi^2}$. Where $t$ is a fixed real number.

I am looking at the sequence $\cos\sqrt{t+\pi^2}, \cos\sqrt{t+4\pi^2}, \cos\sqrt{t+9\pi^2} \ldots \cos\sqrt{t+k^2\pi^2}$. I cannot see a pattern that would bail me out. I also tried differentiation to arrive at a supremum by assuming $n$ to be a continuous variable. I cannot come up with an answer. Any hints?

Comment: For large $n$ this will behave like $\cos(n\pi)$. Now think about parity of $n$.

Comment: @ Anurag A I figure this is because the limit $\frac{\sqrt{t+n^2\pi^2}}{n\pi} = 1 $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\cos \sqrt{t+(k\pi )^2 } =(-1)^{k+1} \cos (\sqrt{t+(k\pi )^2 } -k\pi )=(-1)^{k+1} \cos \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t+(k\pi )^2 } +k\pi }\right)$$
hence $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\cos \sqrt{t+(k\pi )^2 } =\limsup_{k\to\infty}(-1)^{k+1} \cos \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t+(k\pi )^2 } +k\pi }\right) =\cos 0 =1$$ and $$\liminf_{k\to\infty}\cos \sqrt{t+(k\pi )^2 } =\liminf_{k\to\infty}(-1)^{k+1} \cos \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t+(k\pi )^2 } +k\pi }\right) =-\cos 0 =-1 .$$